# 'Converting date and/or time from character string' Question

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a temp table where I need to filter `Effective_Date >= 2018-05-01`. I have tried different variations of playing around with both the character type (DATETIME2) as well as the WHERE criteria but get the below error message:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 164
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

```
DROP TABLE #EarnedPremium
GO
CREATE TABLE #EarnedPremium
       ([Policy_Number] VARCHAR(250)
      ,[Effective_Date] DATETIME2
      ,[Earned_Premium] MONEY
       )
GO      
INSERT INTO #EarnedPremium
SELECT 
      Policy_Number
      ,Effective_Date
      ,Earned_Premium
FROM dbo.AGG_EarnedPremium
WHERE Effective_Date >= '%2018-05-01 00:00:00.0000000%'

SELECT * FROM #EarnedPremium
```

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Why do you have `%` symbols in your date string?

Comment: Why you are using `%` there? it's not a part of a valid datetime. Just use `'2018-05-01 00:00:00.0000000'` and you'll be fine

Comment: Hi @DaleBurrell and Sami, I used % as a wildcard while trying to figure out how to get around the above error. I've noted that this is not applied to datetime, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`%` is used for `LIKE` which is an operator for comparing strings for pattern matching.

You want to compare dates based on ordering.  Comparing strings for matching patterns and comparing dates based on time really have nothing to do with each other.

Just use date comparisons:

```
WHERE Effective_Date >= '2018-05-01'
```

Comment: The OP mentions `DATETIME2`, so this is fine, But - worth to mention - with `DATETIME` this will be culture dependant. Try this: `SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
DECLARE @d DATETIME='20190110';
SELECT CASE WHEN @d<'2019-05-01' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;` and try it with `LANGUAGE GERMAN`. Better was the unseparated format, ISO8601 with "T" and time or the ODBC format as `{d'2018-05-01'}`...